# Can I write code to automatically enable DropDownList?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I want the DropDownList to automatically enabled once the current one is selected, I wrote code to achieve this, but there's no response on the page.

The code is for users to select multiple course from the drop down list

HTML markup:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" class="form-control form-control-lg"  runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="List_Change"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList5" class="form-control form-control-lg" Enabled="false" AutoPostBack="True" Visible="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="List_Change" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList6" class="form-control form-control-lg" Visible="false" AutoPostBack="True" Enabled="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="List_Change" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList7" class="form-control form-control-lg" Enabled="false" AutoPostBack="True" Visible="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="List_Change" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList8" class="form-control form-control-lg" Enabled="false" AutoPostBack="True" Visible="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="List_Change" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList9" class="form-control form-control-lg" Enabled="false" AutoPostBack="True" Visible="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="List_Change" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList10" class="form-control form-control-lg" Enabled="false" AutoPostBack="True" Visible="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="List_Change" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList11" class="form-control form-control-lg" Enabled="false" AutoPostBack="True" Visible="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="List_Change" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList12" class="form-control form-control-lg" Enabled="false" AutoPostBack="True" Visible="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="List_Change" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList13" class="form-control form-control-lg" Enabled="false" AutoPostBack="True" Visible="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="List_Change" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList14" class="form-control form-control-lg" Enabled="false" AutoPostBack="True" Visible="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="List_Change" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

C# code:

```
static int i = 4;

protected void List_Change(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddlid form1.FindControl("DropDownList" + i) as DropDownList;

    while (i <= 14)
    {
        if (ddlid.Enabled && ddlid.Text != "--Select Course--")
        {
           ++i;
           ddlid.Enabled = true;
           ddlid.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
           break;
        }
   }
}
```

The page loads fine without any errors but there's no response once I selected the course on `DropDownList4`

Comment: Use the debugger. Put a breakpoint on the first line of your _List_Change_ method and then follow the code inspecting your variables to see if they contain correct values and try to understand what is happening there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is not correct; There is no need to use a static variable. Also, the loop is unnecessary and finally the main reason is that the next the if block always checks the current dropdownlist.

Simply check only the next dropdownlist and not all of them:

```
protected void List_Change(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList current_ddl = sender as DropDownList;
    string id = current_ddl.ID;
    if (current_ddl.SelectedIndex == 0) // "--Select Course--"
    {
        int N = int.Parse(id.Replace("DropDownList", string.Empty));
        do
        {
            string next_id = $"DropDownList{N + 1}";
            DropDownList next_ddl = form1.FindControl(next_id) as DropDownList;
            if ((next_ddl == null))
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                next_ddl.Enabled = false;
                next_ddl.Visible = false;
                next_ddl.SelectedIndex = 0;
                id = next_id;
                N++;
            }

        } while (true);
    }
    else
    {
        int N = int.Parse(id.Replace("DropDownList", string. Empty));
        string next_id = $"DropDownList{N + 1}";
        DropDownList next_ddl = form1.FindControl(next_id) as DropDownList;
        if ((next_ddl != null))
        {
            next_ddl.Enabled = true;
            next_ddl.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```